# How to Execute a Storyboard of the events of any control in xaml in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger, eventtrigger, wpf-style

I'm using C# WPF and have a Animation Style for the `Border` that is inside of a `Grid` that raise on `MouseEnter` event

```
   <Style x:Key="Atash" TargetType="Border">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.BlurRadius)" >
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="12">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="37">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" >
                            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="5,3">
                                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                </EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingThicknessKeyFrame>
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" >
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF4CAF50">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                </EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingColorKeyFrame>
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="#FF4CAF50"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
           </EventTrigger>
        </Style>
```

**What I need:**

when I set the Style of my Border to `Border x:Name="border2" Style="{StaticResource Atash}"` The animation starts when the `MouseEnter` event occurs on the `Border` itself (mouse on the border).
But I want my animation to be executed in all the events that I want according to several specified controls.

I mean that I can set this style on the grid as well : `Grid Style="{StaticResource Atash}"`

Why,
because I want this animation to run when the mouse is on the grid, not just for the border

**Long story short** : I want to do the animation on any event in any control that I want to call, but only in ***XAML***. I don't want to use code behind

Thanks

May related link:

- [WPF/XAML: multiple controls using the same events - is there an easier way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196456/wpf-xaml-multiple-controls-using-the-same-events-is-there-an-easier-way)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/48b22609-9055-4d3b-8f26-b87305e2dc8e/how-to-handle-child-event-in-parent-control?forum=wpf
- [start wpf animation from other element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928980/start-wpf-animation-from-other-element)
- https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/227733/Passing-events-from-child-to-parent-controls-built

.

***Update***
**Full XAML Code**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp11.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp11"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="Atash" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)">
                            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1,1,10,1">
                                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                </EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingThicknessKeyFrame>
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#FF23A232">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                </EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingColorKeyFrame>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="DoOnOut">
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)">
                            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1,1,10,1"/>
                            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1">
                                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                </EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingThicknessKeyFrame>
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF23A232"/>
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="White">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                </EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingColorKeyFrame>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid Background="#FF1B1B1C">
    
    <Grid x:Name="GrdBtn2" Style="{StaticResource Atash}" Margin="323,167,345,135">
        <Border x:Name="border2"  Visibility="Visible" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="5,3" CornerRadius="80" Cursor="Hand" Width="auto" Height="auto" Background="#FF4CAF50">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="White" BlurRadius="12" ShadowDepth="0"/>
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
        <TextBlock  Text=" Automasion"  LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight" LineHeight="20" TextAlignment="Center" Width="auto" Height="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="25,22,27,21" Foreground="White" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Error On MouseEnter of `Grid`:**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: ''BorderBrush' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)'.'
```

Comment: is there any way ? please give advice

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `TargetType` of the `Style` to `FrameworkElement`, you can apply it to any `FrameworkElement` including a `Grid` and a `Border`:

```
<Style x:Key="Atash" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
...
```

Obviously you cannot animate the `BorderThickness` of anything else than a `Border` though.

Your animation also assumes that the `Background` of the element to be animated is set to a `SolidColorBrush` and that it has a `DropShadowEffect` applied.

Comment: I have updated my question may I ask you to please check, I need to run storyboard on others control's events

Comment: I know all engineers work hard and try to help everyone with their question, but it's rare that the experts see your question, is there any way to contact you?

Comment: For your animation to work, you need to set the `BorderBrush` property to a `SolidColorBrush`, e.g.: `<Border ... BorderBrush="Black" />`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. You specify the event to start the storyboard using the `RoutedEvent` property of the `EventTrigger`.

Comment: Because I couldn't set a style using it to set the grid element so that the mouse that came on the animation grid related to the border doesn't fall into that grid, I got here.

Comment: As mentioned, it makes no sense to try to animate the `BorderThickness` property of anything else than a `Border`. So you should probably use a specific `Border` style if you want to animate this property as part of the style.

Comment: I am making a button using grid-textblock-border so that I can apply a blur effect only on the border without affecting the text.